# BackboneJS - Layout issue

Tags: backbone.js

How does it work with Backbone, when I want 3 different layouts? Forexample when page1 would have this layout:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftBlock">
      ...load view here...
    </div>
    <div id="centerBlock">
     ...load other views here...
    </div>
    <div id="rightBlock">
    ...load additional views here...
    </div>
</div>
```

and my second page would have the layout looking like this:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="centerBlock">
     ...load other views here...
    </div>
</div>
```

and my third page would looke like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="topBlock">
    ...load additional views here...
    </div>
    <div id="leftBlock">
      ...load view here...
    </div>
    <div id="centerBlock">
     ...load other views here...
    </div>
    <div id="rightBlock">
    ...load additional views here...
    </div>
    <div id="bottomBlock">
    ...load additional views here...
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using require/handlebars and text plugins...

Answer (score 0):

I assume your using Backbone along with [Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/)? If not, you definitely want to take a look at it, especially for your use case Marionette has special views called [`Marionette.Layout`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md) that do exactly want you want, pretty straight-forward:

1. Define a region `#container` on your `Marionette.Application` object:

   ```js
   MyApp.addRegions({
     container: "#container"
   });
   ```
2. For each of your layouts, define a `Marionette.Layout` with regions for the corresponding views.

   ```js
   Layout1 = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
     regions: {
       leftBlock: "#leftBlock",
       centerBlock: "#centerBlock",
       rightBlock: "#rightBlock"
     }
   });

   Layout2 = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
     regions: {
       centerBlock: "#centerBlock"
     }
   });

   Layout3 = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
     regions: {
       topBlock: "#topBlock",
       leftBlock: "#leftBlock",
       centerBlock: "#centerBlock",
       rightBlock: "#rightBlock",
       bottomBlock: "#bottomBlock"
     }
   });
   ```
3. In the `onRender` callback of each layout, create each view and `show` it within its region, for example:

   ```js
   // within Layout2
   onRender: function() {
     leftBlock.show(new LeftBlockView());
     centerBlock.show(new CenterBlockView());
     rightBlock.show(new RightBlockView());
   }
   ```
4. Depending on your route, show the right layout in your `#container` region.

   ```js
   Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes: {
       'page1': 'page1',
       'page2': 'page2',
       'page3': 'page3',
     }

     page1: function() {
       MyApp.container.show(new Layout1());
     }
     page2: function() { 
       MyApp.container.show(new Layout2());
     }
     page3: function() {
       MyApp.container.show(new Layout3());
     }
   });
   ```

Also see Marionette's [github repository](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette), which contains excellent documentation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly.

Comment: Could the down-voters please be constructive and state whats needed to improve this answer?

Comment: I have removed down-vote since your have improved the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a layout container to separate different layouts inside the container.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="layout1">...</div>
  <div id="layout2">...</div>
</div>
```

Then you can create a master View and 2 layout View like this

```
SubView1 = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#layout1",
  show: function () { this.$el.show();}),
  hide: function () { this.$el.hide();})
});
SubView2 = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#layout2",
  show: function () { this.$el.show();}),
  hide: function () { this.$el.hide();})
});

MasterView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#container",
  initialize: function () {
    this.layout1 = new SubView1;
    this.layout2 = new SubView2;
  },
  showLayout1: function () {
    this.layout1.show();
    this.layout2.hide();
  },
  showLayout2: function () {
    this.layout1.hide();
    this.layout2.show();
  }
});
masterView = new MasterView;
```